# asp.net sessions variables overriding

Tags: asp.net

I have this code at my asp.net application where after pressing button it creates session variable with integer value and redirects to the different page. ID variable is number of biggest number inside mysql database ID column using different method to retrieve it.

```
int ID;

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        ID=ID+1
        Session["ID"]=ID; 
        Response.Redirect("~/NextPage.aspx");
    }
```

What happens if two different users press this button? I mean like 1st user press button with id=5 and after 1 sec 2nd user press this button with id=6. Will first user be able to get ID=5 or variable become ID=6 for him?

Users use different PC's...

Comment: Test it and find out.  `Session` is user-specific tracking at the server, so the values in one user's session should not affect the values in another user's session.

Comment: Where do you set the value of "ID"? From the user's session?

Comment: @David Well I cannot test it because I run this app only in visual studio...

Comment: @Kevin Brechbühl no it simple return method from different class this method simple retrieves Max(id) 'code' command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM ParticipantInfo;"; ID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @EimantasBaigys: You sure can test it.  Run the application, connect to it as one user from one machine and as another user from another machine (or a different web browser on the same machine).  It's a web application, it's open to anybody who makes a request to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are user based. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for more informations.

So in your case, it is no problem: first user will get the `ID=5`, and second user gets the ID increased by himself. If your database MAX(id) did not change between the both user requests, both users will receive the same ID in their session.